# How do I know how much / little code I should include?

Tags: discussion

I've received a message that I could be banned because of my previous question. In retrospect, I understand why. It wasn't informative. With that understanding, I'm not sure how much of my code I should upload. I think I know where the problem is but I'm new to Python so I can't be positive. I would just like some clarification.

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There really isn't anything Python-specific about this (unlike, say, JS, where it's important to talk about how much HTML/CSS to include for browser apps, and when to use the inline fiddle, etc.). Python _might_ benefit from something like [what Rust has](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info), but that's a separate question.